# error yielding two variables at once in python

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning

i am making a function in python to generate a batch of images and yield it back to the main function in two variables but this produces this error **"too many values to unpack expected 2"**

tried to use return instead but got the same error and when returning only one variable it works well.

this is the generator function:

```
def batch_generator(data_dir, image_paths, steering_angles, batch_size, is_training):
    images = np.empty([batch_size, IMAGE_HEIGHT, IMAGE_WIDTH, IMAGE_CHANNELS])
    steers = np.empty(batch_size)
    while True:
        i = 0
        for index in np.random.permutation(image_paths.shape[0]):
            center, left, right = image_paths[index]
            steering_angle = steering_angles[index]
            # argumentation
            if is_training and np.random.rand() < 0.6:
                image, steering_angle = augument(data_dir, center, left, right, steering_angle)
            else:
                image = load_image(data_dir, center) 
            # add the image and steering angle to the batch
            images[i] = preprocess(image)
            steers[i] = steering_angle
            i += 1
            if i == batch_size:
                break
        print(images[0])
        yield images, steers
```

and this is the line that calls it

```
images, steer = batch_generator(data_dir, X_train, y_train, 5, True)
```

i want to return both steers and images as well and can't use return as it will break out of the loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because when you use the `yield` keyword, it makes your function return a generator object instead of a tuple. In order to get all of the different permutations of `images, steer` from your generator you need to do something like this...

```
for images, steer in batch_generator(data_dir, X_train, y_train, 5, True):
    # do something...
```

Answer (score 0):

When you call a generator you create a single generator object, which is an iterable instance. If you just need to pull out just one `yield` worth of values from it, then you can use `next`

```
images, steer = next(batch_generator(data_dir, X_train, y_train, 5, True))
```